# Matplotlib plotting in wrong order

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically I have two arrays, one containing the values of the x-axis and the second containing the values of the y-axis. The problem is, when I do

```
plt.semilogy(out_samp,error_mc)
```

I get this

[image]

Which doesn't make any sense. That is because the plot functions plots everything as it encounters in the x array, not caring whether it's sorted in ascending order or not. How can I sort these two arrays so that the x array is sorted by increasing value and the y axis sorted in the same way so that the points are the same but the plot is connected so that it doesn't make this mess?

Comment: Are input data Python lists or numpy vectors?

Comment: They're lists. Sorry, I should have said that.

Comment: Instead of plotting a line, you can use - as a first step - a scatter plot (to have unlinked points on your graph)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sort by the value of x-axis before plotting. Here is an MWE.

```
import itertools

x = [3, 5, 6, 1, 2]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

lists = sorted(itertools.izip(*[x, y]))
new_x, new_y = list(itertools.izip(*lists))

# import operator
# new_x = map(operator.itemgetter(0), lists)        # [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
# new_y = map(operator.itemgetter(1), lists)        # [9, 10, 6, 7, 8]

# Plot
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.plot(new_x, new_y)
plt.show()
```

For small data, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (as mentioned by other answerers) is enough.

```
new_x, new_y = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))
```

---

The result,

[image]

Comment: I get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack". Trying to figure out what it means. The vectors only contain 50 values. (The error is for the sorted(...) line).

Comment: @akinn, I just undated my answer, including an example.

Comment: Ok, it's working now, thank you. Though, I'm wondering, is it more efficient like this? Using itertools and operator, I mean. The other solution offered by other seem to be working as well.

Comment: @akinn, `zip` needs to fetch all items immediately.  `izip` only advances the underlying iterators.

Comment: @akinn, refer to [itertools — Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) for the detailed description.

Comment: Good point for the MWE, however @Hidde provided a more "modern" and simpler answer for python 3.5

Answer (score 25):

It is easier to `zip`, sort and un`zip` the two lists of data.

Example:

```
xs = [...]
ys = [...]

xs, ys = zip(*sorted(zip(xs, ys)))

plot(xs, ys)
```

See the zip documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to sort the lists would be to use NumPy arrays and use `np.sort()` for sorting. The advantage with using arrays would be a vectorized operation while computing a function like y=f(x). Following is an example of plotting a normal distribution:

**Without using sorted data**

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 200)
f = 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) )
plt.plot(x,f, '-bo', ms = 2)
```

**Output 1**

[image]

**With using np.sort()** This allows straightforwardly using sorted array `x` while computing the normal distribution.

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
x = np.sort(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 200)) 
# or use x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 200).sort()
f = 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) )
plt.plot(x,f, '-bo', ms = 2)
```

Alternatively if you already have both x and y data unsorted, you may use `numpy.argsort` to sort them a posteriori

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 200)
f = 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) )
plt.plot(np.sort(x), f[np.argsort(x)], '-bo', ms = 2)
```

Notice that the code above uses `sort()` twice: first with `np.sort(x)` and then with `f[np.argsort(x)]`. The total `sort()` invocations can be reduced to one:

```
# once you have your x and f...
indices = np.argsort(x)
plt.plot(x[indices], f[indices], '-bo', ms = 2)
```

In both cases the output is

**Output 2**

[image]

Comment: You could still improve performance by using `sort(x)` only once.

Comment: @ThomasKühn: I added it in my answer as an alternative

Comment: I edited the answer to make it a bit clearer. If you disagree you may just revert the change.

Comment: @Sheldore I think you're still using sort twice: first, when you do `np.sort(x)` and then when you do `f[np.argsort(x)]`. I'd instead do `indices = np.argsort(x)` and then plot by doing: `plt.plot(x[indices], f[indices])`

Answer (score 1):

just do this

```
list=zip(*sorted(zip(*(x,y))))
plt.plot(*list)
```

sorted function will sort according to the 1st argument i.e x values

Comment: But, in Python 3, from what I am seeing, it is returning a tuple. I upvoted your answer. However, your list variable is actually a tuple. (By the way, using _list_ as a variable is a pretty bad idea as _list_ is a built-in data-structure and _list()_ initialises a list technically.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your arrays to numpy arrays, then use argsort on the first array, take the the array and sort both arrays with the argsort array.

Comment: I plotted a scatter plot but it's not easy to interpret. Essentially my x vector is the number of iterations, and y is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to sort one array and the other array should also get sorted based on the first array. I got this solution from some other stack overflow question. Most probably this should be your solution.

```
out_samp,error_mc=zip(*sorted(zip(out_samp,error_mc)))
```

Now plot those two values, you get a correct graph.